# Multiple condition `rowSums`

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I would like to perform a `rowSums` based on specific values for multiple columns (i.e. multiple conditions). I know how to `rowSums` based on a single condition (see example below) but can't seem to figure out multiple conditions.

```
# rowSums with single, global condition
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:100,10),
             b = sample(0:100,10),
             c = sample(0:100,10),
             d = sample(0:100,10))
print(df)
   a   b  c  d 
1  31  63 54 49
2  25  88 71 92
3  54  27 53 34
4   5  39 73 93
5  45  73 40 67
6  46  64 16 85
7  77  19 97 17
8  34  33 82 59
9  50  93 51 99
10 15 100 25 11
```

**Single Condition Works**

```
df$ROWSUMS <- rowSums(df[,1:4] <= 50)

# And produces 
   a   b  c  d ROWSUMS
1  31  63 54 49       2
2  25  88 71 92       1
3  54  27 53 34       2
4   5  39 73 93       2
5  45  73 40 67       2
6  46  64 16 85       2
7  77  19 97 17       2
8  34  33 82 59       2
9  50  93 51 99       1
10 15 100 25 11       3
```

**Multiple Conditions Don't Work**

```
df$ROWSUMS_Multi <- rowSums(df[,1] <= 50 | df[,2] <= 25 | df[,3] <= 75)
```

> Error in rowSums(df[, 1] <= 50 | df[, 2] <= 25 | df[, 3] <= 75) : 
>     'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

**Desired Output**

```
   a   b  c  d ROWSUMS_Multi
1  31  63 54 49       2
2  25  88 71 92       2
3  54  27 53 34       1
4   5  39 73 93       2
5  45  73 40 67       2
6  46  64 16 85       2
7  77  19 97 17       1
8  34  33 82 59       1
9  50  93 51 99       2
10 15 100 25 11       2
```

I could just be sub-setting incorrectly, but I haven't been able to find a fix.

Comment: Don't use `,`  in subsetting when there is 1 column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with `[` while having a single row or single column is it coerces the `data.frame` to a vector.  Based on `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

NOTE, `drop` is TRUE by default

and later in the documentation

> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

To avoid that either use `drop = FALSE` or simply drop the `,` which will return a single column data.frame because by default, the index without any comma is regarded as column index and not row index for `data.frame`

```
rowSums(df[1] <= 50 | df[2] <= 25 | df[3] <= 75)
```

#### Update

Based on the expected output, the `rowSums` can be written as

```
dfROWSUMS <- rowSums(df[1:3] <= c(50, 25, 75)[col(df[1:3])])
df$ROWSUMS
#[1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
```

NOTE: Earlier comment was based on why the `rowSums` didn't work.  Didn't check the expected output earlier.  Here, we need to do comparison of 3 columns with  different values.  When we do

```
df[1] <= 50
```

It is a single column of one TRUE/FALSE

When we do `|` with

```
df[1] <= 50 | df[2] <= 25
```

It would be still be a single column of TRUE/FALSE.  Only difference is that we have replaced `TRUE/FALSE` or `FALSE/TRUE` in a row with `TRUE`.  Similarly, it would be the case when we add `n` logical comparisons compared with `|`.  Instead of that, do a `+`, does the elementwise sum

```
((df[1] <= 50)+ (df[2] <= 25) + (df[3] <= 75))[,1] # note it is a matrix
```

Here, we can do it with `vector` i.e. using `,` as well

```
((df[, 1] <= 50)+ (df[, 2] <= 25) + (df[, 3] <= 75)) # vector output
```

The only issue with this would be to repeatedly do the `+`.  If we use `rowSums`, then make sure the comparison value replicated (`col`) to the same dimensions of the subset of data.frame.  Another option is `Map`,

```
Reduce(`+`, Map(`<=`, df[1:3], c(50, 25, 75)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer akrun. Maybe my logic is off, but your answer gives me a column with just values of 1 (since either one or more of the conditions are met in each row). Would it be possible to get my desired output (see edit) where every time the condition is met, the ROWSUMS_Multi column tallies them?

Comment: The Update did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `cbind` to create a matrix from the multiple conditions using column positions or column names then use `rowSums` like usual, e.g

```
> rowSums(cbind(df[,'a'] <= 50 ,df[,'b'] <= 25 ,df[,'c'] <= 75), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2

> rowSums(cbind(df['a'] <= 50 ,df['b'] <= 25 ,df['c'] <= 75), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ROWSUMS=rowSums(cbind(.['a'] <= 50 ,.['b'] <= 25 ,.['c'] <= 75), na.rm = TRUE))
```